# How to return XML in response to HTTP post in Apex?

Tags: xml, apex

I'm trying to return XML in response to an http post with Apex and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. I currently have:

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/routeAPIs/*')
 global class routeAPIController {
     @HttpPost
     global static String getOwner(String interation_id, String source_address, String destination_address) {


        //Get day of the week to check for weekend
        Boolean dayFlag = false;
        Date myDate = System.today();
        DateTime myDateTime = (DateTime) myDate;
        String dayOfWeek = myDateTime.format('E');
        if(dayOfWeek == 'Sat' || dayOfWeek == 'Sun'){
            dayFlag = true;
        }

        try{
            //Query for the owner using the case number entered
            Case A = [SELECT OwnerId, Status, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Case.ContactPhone =: source_address limit 1];
            //Convert OwnerId to string
            String caseOwner = String.valueOf(A.OwnerId);
            //Query for the email of the user using the case owner ID
            User B = [Select Email From User where id = : caseOwner limit 1];
            //Convert email to string
            String ownerEmail = String.valueOf(B.Email);
            //return xml for successful find of case and owner
            //Checks for weekend, else weekday output
            if(dayFlag){
                //Checks if most recent case is closed, else case is open
                if(A.Status == 'Closed'){
                    String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="closed"><Fields><Field name="ringGroup">weekendResponder</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                    return xml;
                }
                else{
                    String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="open"><Fields><Field name="email">' + ownerEmail + '</Field><Field name="ringGroup">weekendResponder</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                    return xml;
                }
            }
            else{
                //Checks if most recent case is closed, else case is open
                if(A.Status == 'Closed'){
                    String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="closed"><Fields><Field name="ringGroup">trafficCop</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                    return xml;
                }
                else{
                    String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="open"><Fields><Field name="email">' + ownerEmail + '</Field><Field name="ringGroup">trafficCop</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                    return xml;
                }
            }
        }
        //If case isn't found or not enough numbers were entered
        catch(QueryException e){
            //If no case is found - Routes to weekendResponder/trafficCop depending on day
            if(dayFlag){
                String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="newNum"><Fields><Field name="ringGroup">weekendResponder</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                return xml;
            }
            else{
                String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="newNum"><Fields><Field name="ringGroup">trafficCop</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                return xml;
            }
        }

        //So end of function can't be reached - Routes to weekendResponder/trafficCop depending on day
        if(dayFlag){
                String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="wrong"><Fields><Field name="ringGroup">weekendResponder</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                return xml;
            }
            else{
                String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Context output="wrong"><Fields><Field name="ringGroup">trafficCop</Field></Fields></Context></Response>';
                return xml;
            }
       }
}
```

The problem with the current code is it returns a string so the response is enclosed in quotes and isn't properly read as XML. I have tried building an xml doc and putting the string as a RestResponse but both times I've gotten the error "Compile Error: Invalid type for Http* method:.." when trying to save it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/parsing-xml-using-the-apex-dom-parser) will give you good example of parsing the XML. To return in string format you need to first convert into DOM and add your child elements and then convert the XML into string using toXmlString();
[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102090/best-practices-for-generating-large-xml-files) will give you example how to convert it

```
  public String toXml() {

  // Create our top level doc and request node
  Dom.Document requestDoc = createXMLRequestDocument();
  Dom.XmlNode bodyNode = requestDoc.getRootElement().addChildElement('soapenv:Body', null, null);
  Dom.XmlNode requestMessageNode = bodyNode.addChildElement('addressValidationRequest', null, null);

  // Add user details
  Dom.XmlNode userDetailsNode = requestMessageNode.addChildElement('userDetails', null, null);
  userDetails.addToXmlDoc(userDetailsNode);

  // Add address
  Dom.XmlNode addressNode = requestMessageNode.addChildElement('address', null, null);
  address.addToXmlDoc(addressNode);

  return requestDoc.toXMLString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answers is too late, but I will leave my solution here because I had the same problem and maybe somebody else could have the same issue.

Its very simple. You need to set your method as void and after that, you only need to build your response.

Check the next code below:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/APIClass/*')

global without sharing class Listener {

    @HttpPost
    global static void postMethod() {

        /*
            // All your logic
        */

        // After that, just build the response as needed:
        String xmlResponse = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"><Ack>true</Ack></notificationsResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'

        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(xmlResponse);
        response.statusCode = 201;

    }

}
```

When the method is executed, the built response is sended back.

Try to do this with the help of [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) or postman to see your responses.